# How to pass environment variables to a sql file from bash shell (PostgreSQL)

Tags: postgresql, psql, bash

I need to be able to pass environment variables, from a bash shell executing a `.sql` file using `psql`.

The `psql` command I am running is:

```
su postgres -c "psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 -v dbname=example -v dbuser=example -e" < ./create-db.sql
```

Where I have put `example` is usually set to `$DATABASE_NAME` and `DATABASE_USER` respectively which is set in the bash script before executing the `psql` command.

The `create-db.sql` file is:

```
\connect postgres
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS :dbname;
DO $$BEGIN
    CREATE USER :dbuser;
EXCEPTION WHEN duplicate_object THEN
    RAISE NOTICE 'user already exists';
END$$;
ALTER ROLE :"dbuser" SET search_path TO :"dbname",public;
CREATE DATABASE :"dbname"
    OWNER=:dbuser
    ENCODING=UTF8
    LC_COLLATE='en_US.UTF-8'
    LC_CTYPE='en_US.UTF-8'
    TEMPLATE=template0;
\connect :"dbname"
CREATE SCHEMA zulip AUTHORIZATION :"dbuser";
```

The variable substitution in the line `DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS :dbname;` works, but everything after fails at the `CREATE USER :dbuser;` line fails and I have tried it as each of the following ways:

`CREATE USER :dbuser;`
`CREATE USER :'dbuser';`
`CREATE USER :"dbuser";`

And it always errors with:

```
You are now connected to database "postgres" as user "postgres".
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS example;
NOTICE:  database "example" does not exist, skipping
DROP DATABASE
DO $$BEGIN
    CREATE USER :dbuser;
EXCEPTION WHEN duplicate_object THEN
    RAISE NOTICE 'user already exists';
END$$;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ":"
LINE 2:     CREATE USER :dbuser;
                        ^
```

I'm really not sure where I'm going wrong with the above. Output of `psql -V` is `psql (PostgreSQL) 12.6 (Ubuntu 12.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)`

Comment: Anonymous code blocks don't accept variables.  Perhaps you could use a temporary function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will allow you to do it.  In your case, everything between '$$' is a "dollar-quoted string constant, so nothing gets interpreted.  See [sql syntax](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-syntax-lexical.html), 4.1.2.4.

```
\set CREDO 'begin create user ' :dbuser '; exception when duplicate_object then raise notice ''user already exists''; end';
do :'CREDO';
```