# psql \set an environment variable from the existing shell environment

Tags: postgresql, linux, environment-variables

I want to set up a psql variable from an existing shell environment variable that I can use in later `psql` commands.

I found the [`\set`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMANDS) meta-command, but I'm not able to make it use an existing environment variable in Linux:

```
user@localhost# MY_DB='test_database'
user@localhost# sudo -u postgres psql
\set dbname ${MY_DB}
\set 
...
dbname = '${MY_DB}'
```

whereas I would like `dbname = 'test_database'` on the last line so that I can use it or example like: `\connect :dbname;`

How could I achieve that with pg 15 on debian 11?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18725880/using-an-environment-variable-in-a-psql-script) is not helping me much because
`` \set dbname `echo ${MY_DB}` `` 
is issuing an empty string.

[This](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/288859/how-to-pass-environment-variables-to-a-sql-file-from-bash-shell-postgresql) neither, because I'd like to set my psql variable only once in order to avoid redundancy and to reuse it in plenty of `psql` commands instead of setting it plenty of times with `-v` in each of those `psql` commands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

psql version 15 provides the `\getenv` metacommand to do this efficiently:

> \getenv psql_var env_var
> Gets the value of the environment variable env_var and assigns it to the psql variable
> psql_var. If env_var is not defined in the psql process's environment, psql_var is not
> changed. Example:
>
> ```
>            => \getenv home HOME
>            => \echo :home
>            /home/postgres
> ```

Please note that it's not enough to define a variable in the shell from which psql is launched: the variable needs to be exported (see `export` with POSIX shells) to be accessible from child processes. This is why in your example, `` \set dbname `echo ${MY_DB}` ``  produces an empty string. Whether you want to use the faster `\getenv` or `echo` in a subshell, you should do `export MY_DB='test_database'`.

Comment: Great, thanks for your nice explanations. A small extra question: how would you do the same on a PG 14 database where `\getenv` is not available?

Comment: @s.k: `\set var \`echo $env_var\`` will also work if `export env_var` was used in the calling shell.